# Cosmological constant in a semiclassical approximation of quantum gravity

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, cosmological-constant, absolute-units

Why is it the case that, in a semiclassical description of quantum gravity, the cosmological constant is small in Planck units?

Why does this mean that

$$\ell \gg G$$

for $\Lambda = - 1/\ell^{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semiclassical gravity (and basically anything known today) doesn't say anything about specific value of the cosmological constant. You can consider quantum corrections to the effective cosmological constant, you can look how it changes during phase transitions but there's always some constant term that is unconstrained by theory. At the present level of understanding we have to treat it as a free parameter with some value taken from observations.

This value is very strange having no obvious relation to any other known scale and when you take into account all the phase transitions and how it should be related to some high energy physics. This is a major unsolved problem of the modern physics.

Comment: You have not mentioned if the fact that the cosmological constant is small in Planck units is an experimental observation. How does this imply that $\ell \gg G$ for $\Lambda = - 1/\ell^{2}$?

Comment: @nightmarish What's $G$? If $\Lambda$ is small what you can say about it inverse?

Comment: I have the following: $\Lambda \ll M_{P}^{4} \implies 1/\ell^{2} \ll M_{P}^{4} \implies 1/\ell^{2} \ll 1/G^{2}_{N} G^{2}_{N} \ll \ell^{2} \implies \ell^{2} \gg G^{2}_{N} \implies \ell \gg G_{N}.$ Is this correct?

Comment: @nightmarish Yes.